# PHP script to download a website with its files

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I need a PHP script that does something similar to the "Save Page As" button in Firefox or other browsers. That is: given a URL, it downloads the associated HTML file, but also the images and other files displayed in it. The `file_get_contents()` function only gets me halfway there, getting the HTML file but not the images or other files. A solution would be to read through the HTML returned by `file_get_contents()` and for every file link found, apply the `file_get_contents()` to it. Yet I suspect there must be a more standard solution already. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to do this in PHP?  `wget` command can be used for this.  You may even be able to use `system` function to execute `wget` (provided it's installed on the system).

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be done in PHP. I can call the `wget` command via the PHP `exec()` function, so problem solved, thanks! If you want to add it as a solution I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `wget` command:

```
wget --page-requisites http://www.yourwebsite.com/directory/file.html
```

From PHP you can invoke it using `exec` or `system`.

Comment: Is there any way to force paths like `/default.css` in the HTML to be transformed to relative paths (`default.css`) so that they work locally without starting any kind of server?

Comment: @str Have a look at `-k` option of `wget` - it may be what you're after.